#  What is the correct way of adding a background image to a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Did read on couple of forums that adding a background image with "colorWithPatternImage" will consume more memory than usual.

The bad way:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Better solution:

```
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]; iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 
self.view = iv; 
[iv release];
```

---

I have two question regarding this! which solution is better ? And why ?
I am also trying to figure out how to place my labels on the top of the imageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIColor* tmpColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];  
self.view.backgroundColor=tmpColor;  
[tmpColor release];
```

Comment: This solution dos not work for me at all becouse the background color behind tmpColor turns out black for some reason.

Comment: No need to sending you the image, its 360p high and 470p wide.
The problem is that all space around this image is colored black.

Comment: Thanx, I think I figured it out. As you sai i resized the image to fit in such way I need it.